# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float IN LIST PYTHON

Tags: python, list, loops

For some reason the line "new1 = [chr(x) for x in new]" cannot take a float. I am converting all the ASCII integers in the 'new' list back to a list with characters, according to their respective ASCII number, this list would be saved as new1.

```
if de == "d":
   num = input("input ur number: ")
   key = int(input("Decryption key?"))
   num = [int(x) for x in num.split()]
   new = [x /key for x in num]
   new1 = [chr(x) for x in new]
```

This is the error:

--Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Encryptiontrue.py", line 23, in 
    new1 = [chr(x) for x in new]

-- File "C:\Python34\Encryptiontrue.py", line 23, in 
    new1 = [chr(x) for x in new]

-- TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Full Code:

```
de = input("Decrypt or encrypt?: ")

if de == "e":
   word = input("input ur text: ")
   word = word.lower() 
   new = list(word)

   key = int(input("what number by?: "))

   new1 = [ord(x) * user for x in new]

   new2 = " ".join(str(x) for x in new1)
   print(new2)

if de == "d":
   num = input("input ur number: ")
   key = int(input("Decryption key?"))
   num = [int(x) for x in num.split()]
   new = [x /key for x in num]
   new1 = [chr(x) for x in new]
```

Comment: What are you inputs?

Comment: `chr(x)` shouldn't take a float because how would you convert something like `26.23` into a ascii character? do an explicit integer conversion in your list comprehension for `new` with `x//key` or `int(x/key)`.

Comment: @RNar Thank you so much! It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
new = [x / key for x in num]
```

To

```
new = [x // key for x in num]
```

In Python 3, `/` indicates "true division" which always returns a float.   `//` indicates "floor division".  Floor division will return an integer if both arguments are integers.  For more details see [PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Comment: I find that a lot of people are confused about the `//` operator.  You might want to explain _why_ changing it to `//` fixes the problem.

Comment: Working on that.  Thinking about just linking to the PEP.

Comment: Actually, I'm not completely sure that will work as `chr(10.//3.)` is still a `TypeError`.  (from the PEP:  `the result type will be the common type into which a
    and b are coerced before the operation`)

Comment: @mgilson:  Good point.  But the OP's code is not using floats so it won't be an issue here.

Comment: Ahh, right.  I didn't look at OP's code closely enough to infer the types of `x` and `key`.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @ClemLanoe:  Make sure you understand why.